# Securing JAX-RS (Jersey) REST API via spring security oauth2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, spring-security-oauth2

I have a REST API implemented with JAX-RS annotations with Jersey. I'd like to allow Facebook, GitHub, etc, logins via OAuth2.

Should I expect to get spring-security-oauth2 working with Jersey/JAX-RS without too much complication, or does spring-security-oauth2 really only work with a real spring web application (for instance, using spring-boot-starter-web)? I can't seem to find any example source code that does this.